# Understanding the results from sklearn logistic regression + random feature elimination

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, rfe

I am training a Logistic Regression classifier in sklearn and using RFECV to reduce the number of features. I have 10,000 data items with 3000 features each. Using RFECV, I get 106 features. The code for this is shown below:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=10000)
rfecv = RFECV(clf, step=0.1, verbose=True)
rfecv = rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train = X_train[:, rfecv.support_]
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And my stats (accuracy, precision, recall and F1 score) all improve (a bit) with 106 vs. 3000 features. However, I did another test to see if I could zero out some of these 106 coefficients. So I just set all the coefficients whose absolute value is below a certain threshold to 0 and I see this:

[image: Stats vs. threshold values]

As I increase the threshold, I do zero out more weights (the percentage of 0 weights are the diamond points). The max absolute value of coefficients is 1.62 so zeroing everything about 1.7 means 100% of the coefficients are 0, so the 1.6 and 1.7 lines make sense.

But it seems like the stats stay pretty steady as I zero more weights till threshold = 1.2 or so. But I am zeroing out 93% of the coefficients by this point. I thought I would see a more gradual decrease in the stats from 0 till 1.6 but it seems like there is a sharp change only at around 1.2-1.3.

So am I doing something wrong with sklearn and how to use RFECV? Or is this something about logistic regression that I'm not understanding. Or is it just that for this dataset, I can actually predict the class just as well with 3000 or 100 or just 5 features?

Comment: Interesting. I am not an expert, but I am dealing with something similar myself.  The precision is very high. Could it be you have an imbalanced class variable, not many positives?

Comment: @BorutFlis So these results are using 5000 data items each for the positive and negative classes.